# What bug is this behind my drapes?

Tags: bugs, bug-identification, ticks

I decided to wash my drapes and when I looked behind the couch and the drapes I found a ton of these bugs. I'm freaking out that I might have a tick infestation.

What are these bugs? Can they climb out of my vacuum cleaner?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add an approximate location? And if possible, better images? They don’t appear to be ticks, IMO, but I can’t really identify them from those photos

Comment: In general though, bugs can often (likely depending on your exact vacuum cleaner) escape after being sucked up, so you may want to dump the container into a trash bag and deal with it.

Comment: I can't take a picture anymore (thank god :) :)) because I vacuumed them all. Most important thing is that these are not ticks. There was also a lot of dead mosquitoes behind the curtains and sofa. Maybe that's a hint as to what these are? Some kind of mosquito eaters?

Comment: I'm hazarding a guess at some sort of weevil, but it is very hard to be sure without better images. Most weevils are plant eaters as far as I know.

Comment: The approximate location is Montreal by the way

Comment: From the pictures, it looks like a stink bug to me https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_marmorated_stink_bug

Comment: My guess would be weevils.

Answer (score 4):

They are definitely not ticks, those are way smaller and flat. These look much bigger, especially compared to the window. I cannot see it clearly, but my first guess would be that it's a vine weevil. Some bigger photos and infos about your whereabouts (continent, country, latitute etc) would narrow the results down.

Comment: They mentioned Montreal, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Not ticks, not carpet beetles and definitely not stink bugs - the body shape is completely wrong, unless the photos are wildly inaccurate, and stink bugs would be significantly bigger.  The 'snout' in the first photo does indeed suggest a weevil of some kind, or some related type of snout beetle.  I would guess that you have a potted plant of some kind in your living room, possibly recently bought, and the adult beetles (whose larvae were feeding on it) are just attracted to the light of the window behind the curtains.

What kind of beetle, though, I cannot even guess; there are lots of snout beetles!

Answer (score 0):

They look like stink bugs. You may notice an odor in your vacuum since they smell bad when smashed. They are a nuisance but don't really harm anything. [image: High resolution of a stink bug with straight antenna and characteristic shield shape]

Comment: these look much smaller than stink bugs, also they seem to have prolonged heads

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell based on those photos, but based on the photos and your description, I suspect these are [common carpet beetles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthrenus_scrophulariae). These are small 2-4mm beetles who grow from larvae that eat certain fabrics. They are usually found around undisturbed fabrics such as an idle guest bed or unused curtains.

Comment: Good option - legs on carpet beetles are usually quite thin and less obvious than those in the photo though, and the head less obviously separated from body.